# Is VS2013 compatible with the TFS 2012 Build Agent

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

We have TFS2012.2 and have attached a build server, we will want to build ASP.NET projects and so are now trying to decide whether to put VS2012 or VS2013 on the build server.

Some people are using VS2012 and some are using VS2013, I can make them all switch to VS2013 if neccessary as they all have MSDN licences (PRO level).

I expect we will upgrade TFS to 2013 eventually, but not planned.  I can't find anything about compatibility on the web so I would lean towards installing VS2013 on the build server to save time for future.

Maybe there are issues though?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. VS2013 communicate with the build data over Web Services. The build agents and controller communicate with SOAP over HTTP between them. The TFS architecture allows broad client tier compatibility where issues mostly related to the server layers (controller, agents, IIS).

[image: Network ports and protocols]

Comment: Interesting, somehow don't think it directly answers my question.

Comment: You've asked if VS2013 is compatible with TFS 2012 build agent - the answer is yes. Or haven't I understood the question?

Comment: Sorry your quite right, I guess I am looking for some more comment on differences in build process or issues, I'll accept answer early next week and go ahead with VS2013.